# How can you determine if the high harmonic supercontinuum is coherent or not?

Tags: optics, laser, coherence

With the development of suitable mid-IR ultrafast sources to drive High Harmonic Generation (HHG), researchers have reported the development of high harmonic X-ray supercontinuum sources. But how can we determine whether the source is coherent and can be used as a laser?

Answer (score 0):

> how can we determine whether the source is coherent and can be used as a laser?

This sounds like a somewhat confused understanding of coherence, and it's unclear what you mean by 'can be used as a laser'. In particular, it's important to distinguish two different types of coherence:

- spatial (lateral) coherence, i.e. whether different points across the beam are coherent with each other. This can be tested relatively simply by looking for double-slit diffraction patterns using the beam.
- *temporal* coherence is much trickier, and it's basically the Fourier transform of the spectral coherence in the beam, i.e., whether the different frequencies present in the HHG supercontinuum are coherent with each other. This is the case in the microscopic single-atom emission, in which case a coherent supercontinuum represents a single (chirped) attosecond burst of radiation; however, there is in principle no guarantee that the macroscopic phase matching will respect that coherence.

Assuming that you have an HHG source which has been gated (using whatever method you choose) to produce a supercontinuum, the determination of whether that supercontinuum is spectrally coherent is a hard problem and an active area of research. (And, often, disagreement $-$ there are strong incentives to claim the most coherent supercontinua, with the shortest pulses, so some groups might sometimes cut corners in their analysis, or be accused of doing that.) It basically boils down to directly measuring the pulse length and attosecond chirp of the pulse, ideally using a method that does not rely on any assumptions about the pulse, and this is not an easy problem.

I'm not an expert in the field so I don't know that literature in detail, but I understand that [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.99.033403) is the state of the art, and it hopefully provides a good indication of the flavour of that literature as well as suitable references if you want to read more about the problem.